# Force interface implementers to override base class method

Tags: vb.net

I must design an interface in such a way that its implementers(beeing some deriving classes) must override a specific virtual method of their base class. The BaseClass that i'm deriving from can't be modified to set a "MustOverride" specifier for that method.

```
   ' interface
   Interface IFooBar

      Sub SomeMethod()

   End Interface


   ' base class
   Class FooBase

      Protected Overridable Sub SomeMethod()
         ' base code
      End sub

   End Class


   ' derived class
   Class FooBar
      Inherits FooBase
      Implements IFooBar


      Protected Overrides Sub SomeMethod() Implements 
                                   IFooBar.SomeMethod
         ' code
      End Sub
   End Class
```

How can i enforce the "Overrides" specifier on the implementation of the `IFooBar.SomeMethod` ?

Update with detailed information about my implementation:

I have some classes(`DomainObject1`, `DomainObject2`...) which inherits from a base class named `DomainObject` which in turn is capable of validating its properties via attached validation rules. I want a collection for each domain object type, ex: `DomainObject1Collection`, `DomainObject2Collection`, etc. So i derive a `BusinessCollectionBase` from `BindingList(of T)` like this:

`Public MustInherit Class BusinessCollectionBase(of T as DomainOBject)
 Inherits BindingList(of T)`

Notice it has a type constraint of `DomainObject` so deriving collections will only support items deriving from `DomainObject`. 
I want my `BusinessCollectionBase` to override its base `InsertItem` method, in order to attach validation rules to the newly inserted item.
 So the `BussinessCollectionBase` should implement an interface that declares methods to retrieve and attach validation rules when an item is inserted. The code that creates those rules is in derived collection because diferent collection type has different rules. 
Those rules validation will be called by the domain object, when certain property specified by the rule is changed, but the rules are declared in the collection because they are related to it, ex: a domain object should be unique in the collection, checking when any property of the object changes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You mix several concepts in ways that don't make sense. For example, `MustOverride` means a method has no body and its implementers must provide it but your code suggests the base method *does* have code. You want to use interface inheritance to affect a completely different inheritance tree (also doesn't work).

Comment: AFAIK This is not possible if you're not able to modify base class code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not stated that "MustOverride" should be used, you are right, the base method does have code. I updated my original question whith details of my implementation.